# How to create specific python dictionaries with files

Tags: python, file, dictionary

I am trying to create a vocabulary quiz through Python using dictionaries and files. I have two separate .txt files with 10 different words, both formatted as such:

> library: la biblioteca
> school: el colegio, la escuela

and

> to run: correr
> to search: mirar, buscar

I then ask my user to choose which .txt file they want to be quizzed on and how many words they want to be quizzed on.
How do I create a dictionary that has the English words as its keys, and the respective Spanish words as values? I also need to randomly select the words based on the number the user inputs

---

the code I have at the moment is this: (the first function (dict_places) will be duplicated for the second txt file (dict_verbs))

```
def dict_places():
    f = open("places.txt")
    vocab_dict = {}
    for line in f:
        if line.strip():
            key, val = line.split(":")
        vocab_dict[key] = val.split()
        print(vocab_dict)

def main():
    file = input("Please choose one of the following files:\n verbs.txt \n places.txt\nPlease make your choice: ")
    if file == "places.txt":
        print("10 entries found,")
        entries = int(input("How many entries would you like to be quizzed on? "))
        dict_places(entries)
    if file == "verbs.txt":
        print("10 entries found,")
        entries = int(input("How many entries would you like to be quizzed on? "))
        dict_verbs(entries)
```

clearly, I am stuck. Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: `.readlines()` and `.split(': ')`

Comment: "How do I create a dictionary that has the English words as its keys, and the respective Spanish words as values?" Well, what is the rule that tells you where the English word is on a given line? What is the rule that tells you what the Spanish words are on the line - in particular, what is the rule that tells you how to separate the words? Given those rules, can you see how to get a key and a value for a dict, from a line of the file? Given that ability, can you see how to build the dictionary by looking at the file a line at a time? Do you know how to look at the file a line at a time?

Comment: "the code I have at the moment is this" So, what happens when you try the code? How far away is that from solving the problem? In your own assessment, what steps remain to solve the problem, and what part can't you figure out?

Answer (score 0):

```py
def dict_places():
    f = open("places.txt")
    vocab_dict = {}
    for line in f:
        if line.strip():
            key, val = line.split(": ")
            vocab_dict[key] = val.strip().split(", ")

    print(vocab_dict)
```